# Gradle build looking for a non-existent jackson provider dependencies

Tags: gradle, jackson, jax-rs, resteasy

So today I updated my `org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider` dependencies from `5.0.1.Final` to `6.0.0.Final` and can't make the build work again.

```
Could not find jackson-jaxrs-base-2.13.1-jakarta.jar (com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:2.13.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-base/2.13.1/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.13.1-jakarta.jar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

The issue seems rather obvious. But why? The dependency is pulled in transitively from two sources:

```
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin -> 2.13.1
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.1
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.13.1
|    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:2.13.1 (c)
```

and

```
+--- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:6.0.0.Final
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.3 -> 2.13.1
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.13.1
|    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:2.13.1 (c)
```

So far so good. The bit I can't figure out is where is the `-jakarta.jar` piece coming from and why doesn't it exist in the [repo](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-base/2.13.1/)?
I could find corresponding `-jakarta.jar` artifact for versions 2.12.x but the 2.13.x do not exist. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like 2.13 [made changes](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.13#jakarta-variants-to-replace-javax-modules) to using new dependencies for Jakarta namespace. You need to use 2.12 for RESTEasy 6. You can file an issue at https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RESTEASY if you'd like RESTEasy to upgrade to 2.13.x.

Comment: Thank you! I see where the issue comes from now. It comes from the spring-boot-dependencies project and takes precedence. The resteasy-jackson2-provider depends on 2.12.3. I will raise the issue, I believe the upgrade and move away from the classifier is the way to go.